# How can I display multiple images of single image field each in a different row?

Tags: views, 8

I need to render multiple images that belongs to single image field, each on its own views row.

While on a view single field setting, inside "Multiple field settings", uncheck " "Display all values in the same row", But all values are still displayed on same views row.

How can it be done in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

Well, on the same view, on English side of the website the view displays same field, of same field of the same node ID, on separate view rows.

Problem disappeared after the field configured to be to be translate.

Now display every item (image) on its own views row as expected.